# Finding a replacement for the scoreboard player test

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I was trying to use the command `/scoreboard players test @p Objective 1` in 1.14.2, but it seems like 1.14 has changed every command in Minecraft. I need help finding a replacement for this command.

I want to explain why this question is unique. For the first, the example of a possible duplicate of my question is not the same because I asked about scoreboard commands and not to check blocks, and I want to quote this comment:

> MBraedley: Same answer does not make for the same question, so I would
>   not close this question as dupe (at least to the proposed target).

Even though I don't think its the exact same answer, because the only same thing about the answer was `/execute if` and the continued answer was `score player objective matches 1`, and my point with this answer was that you can't use `/scoreboard players test objective 1\` anymore, and if you want to test a score, you have to use the answer I provided, or at least if you want an exact replacement for the command I mentioned in my question.

Since Minecraft 1.13 & 1.14 they have reworked many or maybe nearly all the commands in Minecraft, and for me, and for a lot of people, this has been very confusing, and I have had to learn much of the commands over again, or adjusting my commands.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any testblock equivalent in 1.14? If so, how would it be used to test for a dispenser with held items?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/352386/is-there-any-testblock-equivalent-in-1-14-if-so-how-would-it-be-used-to-test-f)

Comment: This is not an exact duplicate, but the message is the same: Don't think of it as "do this test, then activate redstone, which activates another command block, which then does an action", but instead of "do an action if XYZ or to ABC", which works in just one command and is much better in many ways.

Comment: Same answer does not make for the same question, so I would not close this question as dupe (at least to the proposed target).

Comment: While I generally think that questions with the same answer are duplicates, I don't think this is a duplicate because the proposed duplicate doesn't answer this question because it doesn't talk about `/execute if score`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. Instead of using `/scoreboard` you use `/execute if`, so `if` works like `test` used to. Here is my full command:

`/execute if score MaxVulpes CoordinatesBook matches 1`

`/execute if score  (Player)   (Objective)   matches 1`

Answer (score 0):

Ive been doing reseaerch about this for the past two days and I've finally found one!
Use:

"Execute as  if score   <choose from matches, =, >, <, etc.> "

Example:
`execute as @a if score @p money matches 50..`

TIP: If you place 2 periods after the score such as shown from the above "50.." it would mean that you are trying to tell the computer that a certain action must be executed if the score Is equal to that number and up until above. But if you place those 2 periods BEFORE the score it would mean to execute a certain action if the score is equal to that number score and up below.